Algorithm computing invariants of $\mathrm{SL}(2)\curvearrowright\mathbb{A}^5$.
Consider a field $\Bbbk$ of characteristic zero. The natural action $\mathrm{SL}(2)\curvearrowright\Bbbk^2$ induces an action on $\Bbbk^5\cong\mathrm{Sym}^4(\Bbbk^2)$. View $\Bbbk^5$ as the affine space $\mathbb{A}^5$. I want to use a computer to get generators of the invariant subring $\Bbbk[\mathbb{A}^5]^{\mathrm{SL}(2)}$.
I tried the following method.

Consider the graph of the action $\mathrm{SL}(2)\times\mathbb{A}^5\to\mathbb{A}^5$ as a subvariety of $\mathbb{A}^{2\times 2}\times\mathbb{A}^5\times\mathbb{A}^5$. If we label variables such that $\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{A}^{2\times 2}\times\mathbb{A}^5\times\mathbb{A}^5)\cong\Bbbk[g_{11},g_{12},g_{21},g_{22},x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,y_0,y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4]$, then the ideal cutting out the subvariety is
$$I=(\;\det(g_{ij})-1,\; y_i-(g.x)_i\;). $$
Eliminate $g_{ij}$ to get
$$J=I\cap \Bbbk[x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,y_0,y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4]$$which involves calculating Gröbner basis. This is where my program fails to terminate.
According to Derksen, Kemper Section 4, we get a set of generators as follows. Take a set of generators $f_1,\cdots,f_r\in J$ of the ideal $J$. Let $y_i=0$ and get $\bar f_1,\cdots,\bar f_r\in\Bbbk[x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4]$. Apply the Reynold operator and then $\mathcal{R}(\bar f_1),\cdots,\mathcal{R}(\bar f_r)\in\Bbbk[x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4]^{\mathrm{SL}(2)}$ are generators.

I tried Singular CAS in Step 2, and fail to get the result in hours. Besides, we can think of this question geometrically as finding the GIT quotient of $\mathrm{SL}(2)\curvearrowright\mathbb{P}^4$. Think of $\mathbb{P}^4$ as the set of 4 unordered points of $\mathbb{P}^1$, and then
$$(\mathbb{P}^4)^{\mathrm{ss}}=\{\text{4 points such that at most 2 coincide}\}\\(\mathbb{P}^4)^{\mathrm{s}}=\{\text{4 distinct points}\}. $$It is then natural to consider the cross ratio of 4 points. We get two invariant polynomials this way.

Are these invariant polynomials generators?

Here are my questions:

What are generators of $\Bbbk[x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4]^{\mathrm{SL}(2)}$?
Are there effective algorithm to get these generators?


This calculation was done long ago by the classical invariant theorists. There are two invariants $I$ and $J$ of degrees $2$ and $3$, which you can find explicit expressions for e.g. here: https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/math/invar.html I don't know what construction you have in mind that produces two invariants out of the cross ratio, which is not quite an invariant (since it's not invariant under permutation), but see: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49571/quotient-space-of-mathbbc5-under-the-action-of-sl2-mathbbc/50171#50171
